# Joining multiple WordPress MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, inner-join

I'm attempting to join four WordPress tables the schema can be seen [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-wordpress-database-demystified/), the query returns nothing though.

Can anyone spot any errors here? I've been studying this for a while and can't see any mistakes

I'm passing in some string values here, the problem seems to be with the inner joins though, or rather the joins on 'term_taxonomy' and 'terms'. If I comment these out the query works. I'm not actually doing anything with the additional tables I'm joining yet. I will be at a later date though.

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT id, a.* FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' a '
            . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' b ON a.ID = b.object_id '
            . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . 'c ON b.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id '
            . ' INNRER JOIN ' . $wpdb->terms . ' d ON c.term_id = d.term_id '
            . ' WHERE a.post_type = "product" '
            . ' AND b.term_taxonomy_id = ' . $grouped_id . ' '
            . ' AND id NOT IN ( '
            . ' SELECT object_id FROM ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' '
            . ' WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (' . $sql_filter . ') '
            . ') '
            . $sql_like;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the terms join you have

```
. ' INNRER JOIN ' . $wpdb->terms . ' d ON c.term_id = d.term_id '
```

INNRER should be INNER